# Saving customized Sprite as an image to local disk

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, actionscript

I have a problem with my Action Script 3 code.
I am to let the user to draw whatever he/she wants in spBoard and then I want to make him/her able to save it in the local disk.
this is the code but this code can only save the spBoard without anything drown by the user in it.

```
import com.adobe.images.JPGEncoder;
import com.adobe.images.PNGEncoder;

 var lineSize: Number = 7;
 var currentColor: Number;

 var spBoard: Sprite = new Sprite();
 this.addChild(spBoard);
 spBoard.x = 280;
 spBoard.y = 23;
 drawBoard();

 var shDrawing: Shape = new Shape();
 this.addChild(shDrawing);
 shDrawing.x = 280;
 shDrawing.y = 23;

 var shMask: Shape = new Shape();
 this.addChild(shMask);
 shMask.x = 280;
 shMask.y = 23;
 drawMask();
 shDrawing.mask = shMask;
 var doDraw: Boolean = false;

 function drawBoard(): void {
 spBoard.graphics.lineStyle(1, 0x000000);
 spBoard.graphics.beginFill(0xFFFFFF);
 spBoard.graphics.drawRect(0, 0, 250, 250);
 spBoard.graphics.endFill();
 spBoard.filters = [new DropShadowFilter()];
 }

function drawMask(): void {
shMask.graphics.lineStyle(1, 0x000000);
shMask.graphics.beginFill(0xFFFFFF);
shMask.graphics.drawRect(1, 1, 249, 249);
shMask.graphics.endFill();
}


spBoard.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, boardDown);
spBoard.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, boardUp);

function boardDown(e: MouseEvent): void {
var curX: Number = shDrawing.mouseX;
var curY: Number = shDrawing.mouseY;
doDraw = true;
shDrawing.graphics.lineStyle(5, 0x000066);

shDrawing.graphics.lineStyle(lineSize, currentColor);
shDrawing.graphics.moveTo(curX, curY);
}

function boardUp(e: MouseEvent): void {
doDraw = false;
}

spBoard.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_MOVE, boardMove);

function boardMove(e: MouseEvent): void {
var curX: Number = shDrawing.mouseX;
var curY: Number = shDrawing.mouseY;
if (doDraw) {
    shDrawing.graphics.lineTo(curX, curY);
}
e.updateAfterEvent();
}


save_image.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, save_image_function);
function save_image_function(event:MouseEvent):void
{
var bmd:BitmapData = new BitmapData(50,50);
bmd.draw(spBoard);
var encorder:PNGEncoder   = new PNGEncoder();
var bytes:ByteArray = PNGEncoder.encode( bmd );
var file:FileReference    = new FileReference();
file.save( bytes, "Image.png" );
}
```

Comment: its better leaving some comments on your code, and telling some thing about functions used in this class, assume its first time that we r looking at this lines.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you are drawing in `shDrawing` and then, saving `spBoard` !!
spBoard does not contain any drawn grapgic yet!
you must copy *Draw graphics* into `spBoard` sprite before saving it.
also i used a 250x250 size for bitmapdata inside *save function* to covering whole of the drawing board.

---

```
function save_image_function(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    var _filters:Array = spBoard.filters;
    var defaultHolder:Sprite = new Sprite();
    defaultHolder.graphics.copyFrom(spBoard.graphics);
    spBoard.filters = [];
    spBoard.graphics.copyFrom(shDrawing.graphics);
    // above lines just for getting a back up of spBoard


    var bmd:BitmapData = new BitmapData(250, 250);
    bmd.draw(spBoard);
    var encorder:PNGEncoder   = new PNGEncoder();
    var bytes:ByteArray = PNGEncoder.encode( bmd );
    var file:FileReference    = new FileReference();
    file.save( bytes, "Image.png" );

    // now retrieve default spBoard to what that was before the save process
    spBoard.filters = _filters;
    spBoard.graphics.clear();
    spBoard.graphics.copyFrom(defaultHolder.graphics);
}
```

Comment: can you please tell me how to save the file in Android devices. Thanks for your time and answer

Comment: @Maziar no difference, just define required permission  to write files, that's included inside the XML file, (commented). also don't forget accepting answers if they are right. ممنون

Comment: I have tried some in fileName-app.xml file like but it didn't work. Have you done this before? I had been told that when it even saved,  the file will be in the app directory. I want to get it in folder of my phone like Download. Can you help me in that?!

Comment: @Maziar  try it [Link1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14387919/write-file-in-adobe-air-for-android) and [Link2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24731404/save-file-to-sdcard-as3-air-for-android)

Comment: the first link is the one that i want to do, but it does not work for me. maybe I am putting it in the wrong place. can you lead me on that?